# NodeJS JSON file Read without newline characters

Tags: json, node.js

I am reading a JSON file using  fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8'); but the results include newline characters, and the output is getting like:

```
"{\r\n    \"name\":\"Arka\",\r\n    \"id\": \"13\"\r\n}"
```

How do I avoid these characters?

my local file looks like:

```
{
  "name":"Arka",
  "id": "13"
}
```

Comment: Remove them from the file ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: this is not a solution. i have to modify from nodejs only

Comment: Was joking. Added an answer below ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its unnecessary to read JSON in using `fs.readFileSync()`. This requires you to also write a `try`/`catch` block around the `fs.readFileSync()` usage and then use `JSON.parse()` on the file data. Instead you can require JSON files in Node as if they were packages. They will get parsed as if you read the file in as a string and then used `JSON.parse()`, this simplifies the reading of JSON to one line.

```
let data = require(fileName)
console.log(data) // { name: 'Arka', id: '13' }
```

If you want to serialize the parsed JS object within `data` to a file without the new line & carriage return characters you can write the JSON string to a file using `JSON.stringify()` only passing in `data`.

```
const {promisify} = require('util')
const writeFile = util.promisify(require('fs').writeFile)
const data = require(fileName)

const serializeJSON = (dest, toJson) => writeFile(dest, JSON.stringify(toJson))

serializeJSON('./stringify-data.json', data)
  .then(() => console.log('JSON written Successfully'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Could not write JSON', err))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could read the file and then remove them with a regex:

```
var rawJson = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8');
rawJson = rawJson.replace(/\r|\n/g, '');
```

Keep in mind though that for parsing JSON with `JSON.parse`, you don't need to do this. The result will be the same with and without the newlines.